# Translating 1914 Postcard in German sent from USA to Germany

Tags: united-states, germany, palaeography, 1910s, german-language

Is anyone able to translate this 1914 postcard my grandfather sent to his sister in 1914?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. What parts of the postcard have you already translated, or at least taken a guess at?  Our volunteers are usually happy to help with where you are stuck on your translation but we do not offer a translation service of full documents, even small documents like postcards.

Comment: There is a "Genealogy Translations" group on Facebook that I have found very helpful in the past.

Comment: There is also reddit.com/r/kurrent which can help transcribe letters.

Answer (score 3):

German:

```
Liebe Johanna,
Die besten Grüße von Philadelphia sendet dir dein Bruder Josef.
Liebe Grüße an Euch u Eltern sowie auch an meine Schwester Maria.
Verschließt euren Brief mit einer Reklamemarke.
```

English:

```
Dear Johanna,
Best greetings from Philadelphia from your brother Josef.
Greetings also to yours and our parents, as well as my sister Maria.
Seal your letter with a poster stamp.
```

Addressed to:

```
Fräulein Schmid,
Ulm a/ Donau
Wörthstraße 62
Württemberg
Germany
```

Comment: Because of "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" in this comment: "Würtemberg" is missing a t: "Württemberg" and I read the original as "an Euch u Eltern" instead of "an Euch & Eltern". I also think it might be "Ulm a/ Donau".

Comment: @nebulon42 I've made the changes you suggested. Thanks!